# Mac App Development: How to select app language while installing?

Tags: c++, macos

I am currently developing a Mac app using C++.
In this app, we have provided language selections for users.

But for some resource files, users can change it while using the app. So I want the the language version of the resource files to be chosen during installation and can not be changed after installation.
I have tried to package the app as a .pkg file using packagemaker and iceberg, but I can not find a way to provide a dialog to let users choose language.

For example, when I use iceberg to package a Mac App, it provides those options:
Settings/Documents/Scripts/plugins/Files

I can not find any way to give a language selection for end users.

So, my question is, how can I implement this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, this just is not done.  On the Mac, and within iOS, there is a nearly thirty-year history of supporting a single binary with multiple user interface languages.   The reason that there are few, if any, tools that support installation of just one is that it is considered to be against e way the platform is supposed to work.

Consider, just as an example, a computer in a lab in Quebec where it is not uncommon to have a mix if students speaking English and French.  In is case, lab computers installed with just French would be useful only to users who speak Frennche, as changing the language to English for a new user (at login for example) would result in your application continuing to run in French.

With few exceptions, Applications should contain all languages available and gracefully handle language changes during use (often waiting until they are restarted to change the interface language, but your tactic may very).